# Rest Api Header Authorisation

Tags: .net

I am trying to access a REST webservice. but i am getting this error: 401 Authorization failure.

my code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

   url = "https://example.biz/api/v1/orders/"
        Dim uri As New Uri(url)
        Dim my_request As HttpWebRequest
        my_request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        my_request .Method = "GET"
        my_request .Accept = "application/json"
        my_request .ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
my_request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Digest" & System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")))

'art_request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + 'Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username" & ":" & "password")))
Dim my_request As HttpWebResponse = my_request.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Probably you need a space between Digest/Basic and credentials.

Comment: my_request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Digest " & System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")))  did not help.